# Removing null values on selected columns only in Polars dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to remove null values across a list of selected columns. But it seems that I might have got the `with_columns` operation not right. What's the right approach if you want to operate the removing only on selected columns?

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": ["NY", "TK", "FD"], 
        "eat2000": [1, None, 3], 
        "eat2001": [-2, None, 4],
        "eat2002": [None, None, None],
        "eat2003": [-9, None, 8],
        "eat2004": [None, None, 8]
    }
); df

┌─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ id  ┆ eat2000 ┆ eat2001 ┆ eat2002 ┆ eat2003 ┆ eat2004 │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ f64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ NY  ┆ 1       ┆ -2      ┆ null    ┆ -9      ┆ null    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ TK  ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ FD  ┆ 3       ┆ 4       ┆ null    ┆ 8       ┆ 8       │
└─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘


col_list = [word for word in df.columns if word.startswith(("eat"))]
(
    df
    .with_columns([
        pl.col(col_list).filter(~pl.fold(True, lambda acc, s: acc & s.is_null(), pl.all()))
    ])
)
```

```
Expected output:
┌─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ id  ┆ eat2000 ┆ eat2001 ┆ eat2002 ┆ eat2003 ┆ eat2004 │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ f64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ NY  ┆ 1       ┆ -2      ┆ null    ┆ -9      ┆ null    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ FD  ┆ 3       ┆ 4       ┆ null    ┆ 8       ┆ 8       │
└─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [`polars.col`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/col.html) also accepts Regular expressions which is one way to select all columns that start with a specific string.
- [`polars.all_horizontal`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.all_horizontal.html#polars.all_horizontal) combines all results horizontally (i.e., row-wise) to give a single True/False value per row.

```py
df.select(
   ~pl.all_horizontal(pl.col('^eat.*$').is_null())
)
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌───────┐
│ all   │
│ ---   │
│ bool  │
╞═══════╡
│ true  │
│ false │
│ true  │
└───────┘
```

[`DataFrame.filter`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.filter.html#polars.DataFrame.filter) can be used to keep only the `true` rows:

```py
df.filter(
   ~pl.all_horizontal(pl.col('^eat.*$').is_null())
)
```

```
shape: (2, 6)
┌─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ id  ┆ eat2000 ┆ eat2001 ┆ eat2002 ┆ eat2003 ┆ eat2004 │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ f32     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ NY  ┆ 1       ┆ -2      ┆ null    ┆ -9      ┆ null    │
│ FD  ┆ 3       ┆ 4       ┆ null    ┆ 8       ┆ 8       │
└─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

The `~` in front of the `pl.all_horizontal` stands for negation.  Notice that we didn't need the `col_list`.

One caution: the regex expression in the `pl.col` **must** start with `^` and end with `$`.  These cannot be omitted, even if the resulting regex expression is otherwise valid.

Alternately, if you don't like the `~` operator, there is [`.not_()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.not_.html#polars.Expr.not_)

```py
df.filter(
   pl.all_horizontal(pl.col('^eat.*$').is_null()).not_()
)
```

Or, we can check if there are any non-null values instead:

```py
df.filter(
   pl.any_horizontal(pl.col('^eat.*$').is_not_null())
)
```

##### Other Notes

As an aside, Polars has [other dedicated horizontal functions](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/search.html?q=horizontal) e.g. `min_horizontal`, `max_horizontal`, `sum_horizontal`

Comment: I should have included some information on how to make the `fold` method work.  I've edited my answer to include that, as that is what is in the documentation for the `drop_nulls` method.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is always helpful - I always manage to learn a thing or two (picking more than just the answer!).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement (I wanted to remove empty rows before inserting into a Database but wanted to allow primary keys).
The main difference is I had more dynamic column names, so couldn't use the accepted answer.

I came up with the following:

```
col_list = [word for word in df.columns if word.startswith(("eat"))]
df_filter = df.filter(~pl.all_horizontal(pl.col(col_list).is_null()))
```

This uses [all_horizontal](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.all_horizontal.html) (optionally accepts a list of columns)
and calculates per row if all columns are TRUE.
The **pl.col(col_list).is_null()** tells it to return TRUE if the value is NULL/Empty, else FALSE otherwise.
The **~ in pl.col** flips the is_null so null rows are FALSE
This results in a new series, which equals FALSE if all columns in each row are NULL.

We then use [filter](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.filter.html#polars.DataFrame.filter) to remove all of the rows where the new series is FALSE and return a new Dataframe.
This dataframe now excludes the rows where the specified series have NULL

If you wanted to remove rows where all columns were NULL then you could use a simplified approach with

```
df_filter = df.filter(~pl.all_horizontal(pl.all().is_null()))
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
(
    df
    .filter(pl.col("eat2000").is_not_null())
)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.